# Transparent logging of child process standard streams (Windows)

Tags: windows, logging, stdout, stdin, stderr

I want to create a generic logging application (Windows), which shall be able to execute an arbitrary executable as a child process and log the complete standard streams of a specific to a file (stdin, stdout, stderr).

Further, this logging application shall be acting like a kind of a "Man-in-the-Middle" application completely transparent, so that for user who is calling either the original executable or the wrapper logging application, there is not difference.

This functionality is somehow similar to the UNIX command line tool "tee", but as far as I found out, this tool is unfortunately not be able to log also the stdin (only stdout and stderr are supported). In addition, I want to log some more information e.g. who was the calling parent process, timestamps...

I want to use this especially for the command prompt: "cmd.exe" and rename the original and replace it with my own "cmd.exe" to automatically get a history file of all entered (stdin) commands, with its outputs (stdout, stderr).

Does someone have a good idea how to get this easily realized, perhaps with C# and pipes?

Best Regards,
Andreas

Comment: There's no easy solution.  Processes can tell the difference between a pipe handle and a console handle, and in most cases will behave differently.

Comment: @HarryJohnston should that not be in rare cases? Most console apps probably just use cout/printf and don't care what the other end is. Interactive applications are a different story of course but they are in the minority?

Comment: @Anders, unfortunately, `cout` and `printf` are examples of functions that behave differently for a pipe (buffered output by default) than for a console handle (unbuffered output by default).

Comment: @HarryJohnston but that should not matter in this case, a middle-man or not, the root parent will still be using a pipe if it communicates with its child. With my comment about rare I was thinking more along the lines of something like `more` and terminal applications with a "UI", these have to be different or just fail when they are not directly connected to the console.

Comment: @Anders, I'm not sure what you mean by "the root parent" in this context.  I'm imagining the user running a console-mode program via the wrapper, and expecting to see output on the console that is actually still sitting in the C runtime buffer.  That doesn't matter for very simple utilities that complete quickly (unless they fail to flush the buffer before exiting) and in retrospect I guess that's what you meant.

Comment: ... so, "in most cases will behave differently, although this won't matter for sufficiently simple utilities".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple version would indeed use pipes. In a native win32 app you would create some inheritable pipes and set them and the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag in the [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) struct passed to `CreateProcess`. There is example code for this [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx).

You cannot however use this to replace cmd.exe because cmd.exe also uses the special Windows console API in interactive mode to implement features like the  <kbd>F7</kbd> history "dialog". You could take a look at some of the free terminal replacements like [Console2](https://github.com/cbucher/console) to see how they do it.